# Which Abigail is this?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david

In [Shmuel II 17:25](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.17.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it says:

> וְאֶת עֲמָשָֹא שָֹם אַבְשָׁלֹם תַּחַת יוֹאָב עַל הַצָּבָא וַעֲמָשָֹא בֶן אִישׁ וּשְׁמוֹ יִתְרָא הַיִּשְׂרְאֵלִי אֲשֶׁר בָּא אֶל אֲבִיגַל בַּת נָחָשׁ אֲחוֹת צְרוּיָה אֵם יוֹאָב:
>
> And Amasa, had Absalom set in place of Joab over the host; and Amasa was the son of a man, whose name was Ithra the Israelite, who came to Abigail the daughter of Nahash the sister of Zeruiah, Joab's mother.

Is this speaking about a different Abigail? (and not King David's wife)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. David also had a sister named Abigail/Avigayil ([I Chronicles 2:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a02.htm#15)). That Abigail was Amasa's mother, making Amasa David's nephew.

Comment: Was this a sister from Yishai or from a different man? 
This is so confusing.

Comment: @TheTribeOfJudah From Chronicles, it sounds like from Yishai to me.

Comment: So then was Yishai Nahash. and if that is the case is this the same Nahash of Ammon?

Comment: @TheTribeOfJudah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: The Talmud (BB 17a) says his name was Yishai and he was called Nachash bc he was such a Tzaddik that he was only killed bc of the sin of Adam and Eve and the _snake_ (ie that everyone has to die, even those who don't sin).

Comment: i ask this is because from out of nowhere it mentions that yishai was a tzadik.... What for?  Why is it relevant?

Comment: @TheTribeOfJudah Traditional Judaism would find such a suggestion highly unlikely.

Comment: So after many days. I found an opinion that says that Nahash was the first husband of yishais wife which would make abigail and zeriah stepdaughters to yishai

Comment: @The Cool. Whose opinion is that?

Comment: I'm just so confused by the text. Why would it mention 2 different nahash's 1 right after the next. This must have not been intended. Usually the tenach is very specific it is just unordinary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @DoubleAA said about this Avigail being the sister of Dovid. The sefer Ishay HaTanach by Yishai Chasidah (Shaar Press - 1994) p. 13 notes that Yerushalmi Yevamos 8:3 helps provide more in the way of family background:

> *Yisra the Israelite ([II Samuel 17:25](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.17.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) was born an Ishmaelite. He entered the court of Yishai (father of David) and found him sitting and expounding the verse "Turn to me and you will be saved, all [you who are at] the ends of the earth" ([Isaiah 45:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.45.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Upon hearing this, Yisra became a proselyte and Yishai gave him his daughter (Avigail) in marriage.*